# How to deploy on all GCP instances one-by-one with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a solution to deploy my code on all GCP instances of an instance group with ansible. I would list all instances of an instance group and deploy on them one by one to avoid service interruptions.
Any idea ?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. You must add the "serial" key :

```
serial: <number>|"<number>%"
```

It sets how many hosts at a time to run at a time. The default is to run tasks on all of a play’s machines at once.